# TypeDoc tag to specify version in which feature introduced

Tags: typedoc

Does [TypeDoc](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc) support any specific tag for identifying in which version the feature was introduced?

And if not, then what is the recommended way of adding such a detail?

Answer (score 1):

TypeDoc does not specify a `@version` tag in its set of default tags. However, it does provide the [blockTags](https://typedoc.org/guides/options/#blocktags) option which can be used to tell TypeDoc to parse additional tags.

You could set this from your TypeDoc config, but it is probably better to create a `tsdoc.json` file which extends the base TypeDoc configuration.

```json
{
  "extends": ["typedoc/tsdoc.json"],
  "tagDefinitions": [
    {
      "tagName": "@version",
      "syntaxKind": "block"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I am using the latest typedoc `0.23.16`, but after adding this option I'm getting error: `Tried to set an option (tagDefinitions) that was not declared.`

Comment: @vitaly-t you need to put that in tsdoc.json, not typedoc.json